# AWS Amplify frontend deployment says Access Denied on every request

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, hugo

I followed [this tutorial](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-aws-amplify/). Everything succeeds but when I access the site I get [access denied](https://master.d1jvdwx4rnbunx.amplifyapp.com/). I don't know why this happens I followed the tutorial exactly as it appears.